# How to get HAS_MANY related query data

Tags: php, yii

PLEASE HELP....I AM A NEWBIE

I have 2 tables **PAGE** and **COMMENT.**
**Page** table has columns 
$id 
user_id 
$content 

**Comment** table has columns 
$id
$user_id
$page_id
$date_entered
$comment      **The comment column consist of an array of comments as one user can have many comments**

In the **Page model** the relation in the **relation()** is defined as
'**comments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'page_id'),**

Now in the **PageControllor.php**,I have defined this query in the **actionView()**
**$page = Page::model()->with('user','comments')->findByPk($id);**

---

> ***Now my question is***

**  how can i get the result of this query in **$result** so that i could pass it to the view page as 
**$this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),'result'=>$result))**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the comments to the view file as follows,

```
$this->render('viewname', array(
    'comments'=>$page->comments
));
```

And in your view file, you should do the following,

```
foreach($comments as $c){
    //Display the comment
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you sir...thanks a lot.....i was making a mistake when following your answer..now the problem has been resolved...thanks a lot for your perfect answer.....thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will [pass the variable](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view) `$page` to the view and from inside the view access the comments with `$page->comments` (this will be an array).